# Zooming out of my world: Joints and their positions are not adjusted

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Here is my setup:

- SKScene with a node called world
- to this world, I attach another node: vehicle
- to this vehicle, I attach three nodes that make up the vehicle; a body and two wheels
- the wheels are attached to the body via SKPhysicsJointPin specifying their anchors

Now, everything is fine until I zoom out of my world:

```
[_world runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:0.5 duration:0.75]];
```

My vehicle suddenly lifts off the wheels. It appears as if the same distances as in the not-zoomed-in-world are kept. All parts of the vehicle are properly scaled- except the distances to its parts.

Do I have to apply the zoom to my joints as well? Or do I need to reset the anchor of my joints?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly related: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9624#p51086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physics don't scale. Changing a node's scale is a purely visual effect, it does not alter physics in any way.

Even if you manually update physics positions synchronized with a node's scale you'll find that you can't scale each body's shape without removing the previous body and replacing it with a corresponding body of the same shape, just scaled. During a scale action you would have to through away and create new bodies every frame, which will probably cause a serious framerate issue.

Comment: Steffen, it's you! Thank you for your answer. So basically, I'm out of luck when it comes to zooming out of my scene? Is resizing an option? e.g. self.size = CGSizeMake(newX, newY); as suggested above in the RW blog post link.

Comment: So it does work :) The runAction: was, however, much smoother.